# D365- Application User(Integration user) change business unit issue

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I have an application user which is an Integration user. I am trying to change the business unit of a Application user. But CRM is not allowing me to change the BU. I am getting generic error with logs as below. Did any one faced this issue before. Any leads to solution would be helpful.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #0EC1A276Detail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
<ActivityId>6cfe6e50-d907-4186-ba6e-91c59a1c77c5</ActivityId>
<ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
<ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
<Message>System.Web.HttpUnhandledException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #0EC1A276</Message>
<Timestamp>2017-11-07T07:30:32.9864844Z</Timestamp>
<ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
<ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
<InnerFault>
    <ActivityId>6cfe6e50-d907-4186-ba6e-91c59a1c77c5</ActivityId>
    <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>An unexpected error occurred.</Message>
    <Timestamp>2017-11-07T07:30:32.9864844Z</Timestamp>
    <ExceptionRetriable>false</ExceptionRetriable>
    <ExceptionSource i:nil="true" />
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <OriginalException i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText i:nil="true" />
</InnerFault>
<OriginalException i:nil="true" />
<TraceText i:nil="true" />
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but you could try removing all security roles before changing the BU - you will have to re-assign them afterwards anyway.

Comment: It is not even allowing to remove any of the security Role.

Comment: Does this user own any Workflows/Actions/Processes?

Comment: No as the user is application user, it cannot access CRM via UI and hence no workflows, Action, Process. But yes this particular user calls some Action in crm.

Comment: I did not try myself, but it should still be possible to assign objects to an application user. My bet is on some relation that would be corrupted if the users privileges change during moving to a different BU.

Comment: Are you able to switch another regular user between BUs ? Do you have Any plugin on systemuser entity?

Comment: Did you set the user up as a non-interactive user?

Comment: You could open a ticket with Microsoft Support to pull the log file from the CRM server. It should have some more information.

Comment: I can't update any field on an application user. If I try to update a phone number under details I get the same error. I have even tried to create a new application user, but get the same error when trying to set the user to "non interactive". To me it seems like its something triggering when you have a non interactive user with an application ID set. I have opened a ticket with Microsoft Support and are awaiting an answer.

Comment: FYI, we got a response from Microsoft where they said that the problem is fixed, and I'm now able to update application users again. I suspect that the fix will be rolled out in Service Update 2 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054010/service-update-2-for-microsoft-dynamics-365-8-2-2)

Comment: Even I raised a Ticket to Ms for the same. MS mentioned it has to do with some Plugin form their side and will fix the issue with updating DLL's on server.